# 3 condition IF formula Excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking to create an excel formula with 3 conditions.

Here's what I'm looking for:

`D11` has a number (it is number of working hours). If the number is less than 4 (i.e. `<=4`), then I want it to show a value in cell `B5`,
If the number is between 4 and 8 (i.e. `>4 and <=8`), then I want it to show a value in cell `B6`.
If the number is over 8, then I want it to show a value in cell `B7`.

The cells in `B5, B6 and B7` contain the relevant renimeration for 4-hours shift, 8-hours shift and for overtime.

This is what I have made:

`IF(D11<4,"$B$5",IF(AND(D11>=4,E9<=8),"$B$6","$B$7"))`.

The Formula always gives a message :

> "The formula you typed conains an error: - for information about fixing....;-to get assistance.....; - if you are not trying.......

Please advise!

Comment: Looks ok to me aside from the missing = at the beginning and the rabbits ears around the cell references. Or, are you in a locale that expects `;` rather than `,` in Excel formulas?

Comment: I tried this `=IF(D11<4,B5,IF(AND(D11>=4,E9<=8),B6,B7))` and its working fine for me .

Comment: You dont really need the AND, since D11 will always be greater than 4 when that part of the formula is evaluated, i.e. if D11 is less than 4 the formula will be evaluated to B5, otherwise we know it is 4 or greater when we go on to evaluate  `IF(AND(D11>=4,E9<=8),"$B$6","$B$7")`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and the follwoing is working for me:

```
=IF(B2<4,$E$2,IF(AND(B2>=4,B2<=8),$F$2,$G$2))
```

Here is the example of the data I was working with (replacing `FORMULA` with the above):

```
+-----+----------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
|     |     A    |    B     |    C       |    D        |     E       |    F      |   G    |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1  |    name  | Overtime |    Due     |             |             |           |        |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2  |    bob   |    4     |   FORMULA  |             |     10      |    20     |   30   |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Effectively if B2 is 4 then C2 should show 10.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you. The problem was with the local settings that expect ; rather than , in Excel formulas.

Still I have problem with the formula, because I foud out that I should include one more condition: the case when the person is not working D11=0, because then he/she should receieve 0 or in the cell should be written a text "free day".